# firefox attach event to function

Tags: html, firefox, events, cross-browser

Hy this code work with ie10, chrome 39 but 
no working with firefox 34 : event is not definie.

Do you have idea how to attach the event, without put event on parameter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function show(){
            alert(event);
        }
    </script>
    <div onmousemove="show()">itt a piros hol a piros</div>
</body>
</html>
```